# Combobox unable to change the database

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am working on Microsoft Access right now. I have a combobox, for example, it has "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" in it. I also have a database fields, with the type of boolean, the fields are "a", "b", "c", "d", "e". If user select "a", the database will be filled with "true", "false", "false", "false", "false". If the user select "b", the database will be filled with "false", "true", "false", "false", "false". Etc. I have tried some coding, but none of that work. Oh, and I don't use a button, since in Access you can click New Record and the data will be saved automatically.

Any idea how could my combobox able to change/fill the database at once? Should I use macro in my program to make it happen?

Comment: Found it!! I used the expression builder

Answer (score 0):

For others who might use this thread, here's more help from office.com on using the Expression Builder in Access 2007:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-the-expression-builder-HA010236949.aspx
And here's a demo:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/demo-use-the-expression-builder-HA010254902.aspx